# Flask not able to run on 0.0.0.0

Tags: python, flask

I am not able to run Flask on host 0.0.0.0.
When I run it with 0.0.0.0, it instead shows my Local IP address.

```py
 * Serving Flask app 'application.py' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://192.168.86.147:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you check which IPs it is listening to with a tool like `netstat`? It is possible the output just shows a valid URL for convenience.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is *not* an interface *nor* a valid IP address. It simply means listen on all interfaces. I guess you only have one interface/IP?

Comment: computer may have many `network cards/interfaces` - like wi-fi, wired ethernet, local loop -  and every interface has own IP. You can use this IP to run on on one of interface, or you can use `0.0.0.0` to run on all interfaces.

Comment: BTW: when I run with `0.0.0.0` then I also see my local IP - `192.168.1.28` - and I can connect using `192.168.1.28` (from all computers on local network) or `127.0.0.1` (on current computer).

Comment: It seems that new flask version shows the Local IP but its listening on all interfaces.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @Hardik maybe post your findings (with references) as answer (and accept it), this might help others in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

For an externally visible server on Flask, the documentation asks to run `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` with the expectation being to see

```
$ flask run
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

However you might see your local IP.
As long as you can connect to that IP internally as well as externally, it should work as expected.